# Are references or pointers faster?

Tags: c++, performance, pointers, reference

From what I know, references are just another name for a variable whilst pointers are their own variable. Pointers take up space. People often say "use a reference or pointer" but they don't say which is better. If references take up no memory of their own, then references win in that department. What I don't know is if the compiler makes a distinction between references and normal variable. If you do operations on a reference, does it compile to the same code as normal variable?

Comment: W.r.t. performance, probably not much (run some measurements to check on your platform). I think it is more important to clarify the semantics you want - bear in mind, pointers can be NULL, thus can be argued are optional.

Comment: References are pointers in disguise, the only performance advantage can come from some additional assumptions the compiler can make about them (they cannot legally be reseated, nor can be NULL).

Comment: Conversely, a user may be too afraid to pass NULL pointer even if the pointer parameter is designed to be optional.

Answer (score 3):

Internally references are also implemented in terms of pointer. So, it's difficult to say which is faster pointer/reference.

It's a usage of these two which makes a difference.

For example you want to pass by reference a parameter to the function.

```
void func(int& a)    case_1
{
  //No need to check for NULL reference...
}
void func(int* a)    case_2
{
  //Need o check if pointer is not NULL
}
```

In case_2 you have to explicitly check if pointer is not NULL before dereferncing it whereas that's not the case with references because references are initialized to something.

Assumption is that you are playing game in civilized manner i.e

You are not doing something like:-

```
int*p = NULL;
int &a = *p;
```

Comment: The first part is absolutely right. However, in practice, many NULL checks are not required. Just document in the function comment that you expect a non-NULL pointer and let the null-page crash the program if that precondition is not met.

Comment: In practice you get many segmentation fault due to bad pointer access.

Comment: @cmaster: hopefully you'll avoid those coming from people who explicitly pass `NULL` thinking the parameter is optional.

Answer (score 2):

Here are my two test programs:

Reference:

```
int i = 0;
int& r = i;
++r;
int j = 0;
++j;
```

Pointer:

```
int i = 0;
int* r = &i;
++(*r);
int j = 0;
++j;
```

My compiler wrote the EXACT same assembly code for both.

```
movl    $0, -16(%rbp)   #, i
leaq    -16(%rbp), %rax #, tmp87
movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)  # tmp87, r
movq    -8(%rbp), %rax  # r, tmp88
movl    (%rax), %eax    # *r_1, D.31036
leal    1(%rax), %edx   #, D.31036
movq    -8(%rbp), %rax  # r, tmp89
movl    %edx, (%rax)    # D.31036, *r_1
movl    $0, -12(%rbp)   #, j
addl    $1, -12(%rbp)   #, j
movl    $0, %eax    #, D.31036
```

Comment: Can you dump the assembly with optimization flags on like `-O3` or `-O2` and compare again.

Comment: Better dump with `-Os`, it yields the most readable assembler code.

Comment: I don't want to do that because it'll optimize the entire code away, which isn't helpful.

Comment: All that back and forth from the stack seems to indicate that you compiled this with optimizations disabled, so it isn't meaningful at all... If you want to avoid the compiler to remove the whole thing, at the end assign the result to a `volatile` variable.

Comment: @Matteo Doesn't work for me. I made all the variables volatile and it still optimizes it all away.

Comment: Use a *global* volatile variable for the result, leave the others normal. In alternative, what I usually do is to put each case in a function which returns the result and compile with `-c` (in addition to `-S - O3`).

Answer (score 1):

They are the same, references are just a language mechanic that is a pointer that cannot be null. The difference remains only in the compilation phase, where you will get a complaint if you try to do something illegal.

Comment: They can be NULL in practice, even though the language standard calls undefined behavior at the creation of a NULL reference. The effect is the same as with a NULL pointer. Only harder to debug, since many people will be laboring under the illusion that references can't be NULL, and consequently not understand what is happening in their code.

Comment: They can be, but the code can always assume they aren't.

Comment: You can use the same assumption on a pointer, with the same consequences.

Comment: there can always be strange mistakes, but in a working design references are always valid, and pointers may be null